# Converting Base64 to data returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, base64, uiimage

I am trying to convert base64 string to image, I checked the json response, base64 string is not empty, but Data returns nil in between.

```
let base64String = image.Image_bytes_1
var data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String!, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
imageView.image = image
```

at line#4 getting this below error

> Thread 3: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
> Optional value

Comment: `base64` string in the json may not be empty, but what happens here `image.Image_bytes_1` is probably returning a `nil`. Put this in an `if-let` like so `if let base64String = image.Image_bytes_1` and then process `base64String` .. I don't think you will enter the block. Debug what happens in `Image_bytes_1`.

Comment: i checked it, thats not empty

Comment: it is strange that you don't get a compiler error or at least a warning 
due to using `image` in `let base64String = image.Image_bytes_1` and then 
re-declaring the same name as `let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)`.
Try `let myImage = UIImage(data: data!)` and `imageView.image = myImage`

Comment: and were you able to verify that the base64 string is a valid image ?

Comment: @workingdog : no error if the first image is declared at outer level (struct property for exemple). But I agree that it is not good for maintenance to have multiple object with the same name.

Comment: What is line 64 ?

Answer (score 1):

The Data initializer you are using, `init(base64Encoded:options:)` is declared as `init?(base64Encoded base64Data: Data, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions = [])`

That's known as a "failable initializer", which means it can return nil. (note the question mark after init in the declaration.)

If the `base64` data is not well-formed, it may fail and return nil.

Stop using force-unwrapping. Rewrite using optional binding:

```
if let base64String = image.Image_bytes_1,
   let  data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters), 
   let image = UIImage(data: data) {
      imageView.image = image
} else {
      print("Unable to load base64 data and convert to image")
}
```

### Edit:

As workingdog pointed out in their comment, your code does not make sense:

```
let base64String = image.Image_bytes_1  // line 1
var data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String!, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) // line 2
let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data) // line 3
imageView.image = image // line 4
```

Line 1 references something called `image`. You don't show the code that declares it, so we don't know what it is.

Then in line 3, you declare a new local constant also named `image`. If the original `image` is an instance variable of your class, and the code you posted is inside a function, you are creating a new local variable that overrides the other variable called `image`. I strongly advise against using the same variable name in different levels of scope. That is confusing at best, and causes errors at worst.

Comment: (If one of those steps is failing and you can't tell which one you might need to rewrite it as a series of guard let statements with separate print statements that tell you which step failed.)

Comment: Brother i got crash in line#4

Comment: The lines in the code I posted are not numbered. Which one is line #4? The `imageView.image = image` bit?

Comment: I am referring to my question

Comment: If that line is crashing then perhaps `imageView` is an `IBOutlet` that's declared as implicitly unwrapped? (`@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!` (The exclamation point after the type makes it implicitly unwrapped.) Check to see if `imageView` is nil. If it is, that's another problem to solve.

Comment: Don't use line numbers to talk about code that does not include line numbers. It's confusing. Are you referring to the line (in both your version of the code and mine) that reads `imageView.image = image`?